# Как добавить несколько дней к дате?

Tags: javascript

```
   let date = new Date();

  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let day = date.getDate(); // здесь нужно добавлять некоторое количество дней, чтобы была будущая дата 
// и также был переход на новый месяц в будущем, если так получается по добавленным дням.

  let output =
    (("" + day).length < 2 ? "0" : "") +
    day +
    "." +
    (("" + month).length < 2 ? "0" : "") +
    month +
    "." +
    date.getFullYear();
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте несколько дней к date с помощью `setDate`. Переход на следующий месяц происходит автоматически.

```js
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);
console.log(date.getDate());
```

Comment: у меня в таком случае, вместо дня появляется таймстамп с добавленным значением

Comment: @BlackFire ну так потому что для показа дня используется `getDate()`